# how do I get the location of the user when Internet(wifi/DataPack) is ON in android

Tags: android, location, android-wifi

I am trying to get the location only when user Internet is oN,without using GPS/Network provider.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is get the position using the LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER instead of LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER. The NETWORK_PROVIDER will resolve on the GSM or wifi, which ever available. Obviously with wifi off, GSM will be used. Keep in mind that using the cell network is accurate to basically 500m.

---

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html**

** Has some really great information and sample code.**

After you get done with most of the code in OnCreate(), add this:

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You could also have your activity implement the LocationListener class and thus implement onLocationChanged() in your activity.

Comment: As you have suggested for network provider , I have already tried that but the problem which I have faced is when My wifi / data pack is enable and disable the location services option in setting. than its not helping me out to get the location from internet.

Comment: To obtain the user location in your application, you can use both GPS and the Network Location Provider, or just one. - By google document http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    public void getCurrentLocation() {

        if (mlocManager != null) {
            mlocManager .requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener );
            mlocManager .requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener );
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for getting current location using the internet.

```
public class CurrentLocation extends Activity {

TextView tv;
Geocoder geocoder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_location);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location
            // provider.

            String text = String.format(
                    "Lat:\t %f\nLong:\t %f\nAlt:\t %f\nBearing:\t %f",
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(),
                    location.getAltitude(), location.getBearing());
            tv.setText(text);

            try {


                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                Log.d("Current", addressList.toString());
                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String address_own = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(
                            0);
                    String city = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                    // String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

                    Log.d("Address", address_own);
                    Log.d("City", city);
                    // Log.d("Country", country);

                    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }

                    tv.append("\n" + address_own + ", " + city);
                }



            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data", e);
            }

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location
    // updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```